# How to specify ggplot2 boxplot fill colour for continuous data?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I want to plot a ggplot2 boxplot using all columns of a data.frame, and I want to reorder the columns by the median for each column, rotate the x-axis labels, and **fill each box with the colour corresponding to the same median**. I can't figure out how to do the last part. There are plenty of examples where the fill colour corresponds to a *factor* variable, but I haven't seen a clear example of using a *continuous* variable to control fill colour. (The reason I'm trying to do this is that the resultant plot will provide context for a force-directed network graph with nodes that will be colour-coded in the same way as the boxplot -- the colour will then provide a mapping between the two plots.) It would be nice if I could re-use the value-to-colour mapping for later plots so that colours are consistent between plots. So, for example, the box corresponding to the column variable with a high median value will have a colour that denotes this mapping and matches perfectly the colour for the same column variable in other plots (such as the corresponding node in a force-directed network graph).

So far, I have something like this:

```
# Melt the data.frame:
DT.m <- melt(results, id.vars = NULL) # using reshape2
# I can now make a boxplot for every column in the data.frame:
g <- ggplot(DT.m, aes(x = reorder(variable, value, FUN=median), y = value)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point") +
geom_boxplot(???, alpha=0.5)
```

The colour fill information is what I'm stuck on. "value" is a continuous variable in the range [0,1] and there are 55 columns in my data.frame. Various approaches I've tried seem to result in the boxes being split vertically down the middle, and I haven't got any further. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Maybe something with a built-in data set? We can't run your code without your `results` data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding the median-by-group to your data frame and then mapping the new median variable to the fill aesthetic. Here's an example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame. By using this same mapping across different plots, you should get the same colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>%
         mutate(medMPG = median(mpg)), 
       aes(x = reorder(carb, mpg, FUN=median), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=medMPG)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low=hcl(15,100,75), high=hcl(195,100,75))
```

[image]

If you have various data frames with different ranges of medians, you can still use the method above, but to get a consistent mapping of color to median across all your plots, you'll need to also set the same `limits` for `scale_fill_gradient` in each plot. In this example, the median of `mpg` (by `carb` grouping) varies from 15.0 to 22.8. But let's say across all my data sets, it varies from 13.3 to 39.8. Then I could add this to all my plots:

```
scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(13.3, 39.8), 
                    low=hcl(15,100,75), high=hcl(195,100,75))
```

This is just for illustration. For ease of maintenance if your data might change, you'll want to set the actual limits programmatically.

Comment: Thanks! This was more or less exactly what I was looking for. I'm not familiar with dplyr, but with your help I was able to figure out the rest of the solution, which you can read below.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I implemented it but still get an error `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. Is it possible to do the sample plot if the `x-axis` variable is a factor variable? Can you share an example of that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I built on eipi10's solution and obtained the following code which does what I want:

```
# "results" is a 55-column data.frame containing 
# bootstrapped estimates of the Gini impurity for each column variable
# (But can synthesize fake data for testing with a bunch of rnorms)
DT.m <- melt(results, id.vars = NULL) # using reshape2
g <- ggplot(DT.m %>% group_by(variable) %>%
          mutate(median.gini = median(value)), 
        aes(x = reorder(variable, value, FUN=median), y = value))  +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=median.gini)) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point") +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = heat.colors(9)) +
ylab("Gini impurity") +
xlab("Feature") +
guides(fill=guide_colourbar(title="Median\nGini\nimpurity"))
plot(g)
```

Later, for the second plot:

```
medians <- lapply(results, median)
color <- colorRampPalette(colors = 
heat.colors(9))(1000)[cut(unlist(medians),1000,labels = F)]
```

`color` is then a character vector containing the colours of the nodes in my subsequent network graph, and these colours match those in the boxplot. Job done!